# Issues with mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I just reinstalled Ubuntu and I'm having some problems with the mouse and the keyboard that I can't solve.

- Prior to reinstalling the system, if I held any key, the system would repeat it infinitely (for example, I could erase an entire line just by holding backspace). Now it's not working and setting the keyboard settings to "key presses repeat when key is held down" won't help -- it only makes the key repeat for a short time - it then automatically stops working while I'm still holding the key.
- The mouse is having a similar problem. Before reinstalling, I could could select an entire area of the desktop for how much time I could. Now if I try to do this, the mouse fails and the selection disappears when I'm holding the left button.

Both these features were very useful to me and I can't find any way to bring them back. Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by opening a terminal and typing the following:

```
 sudo su

 echo "blacklist peaq_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf
```

After a reboot, everything works fine.